# Using a for loop, display the number of entries and the sum in Java

Tags: java

so I was asked to create a program in which the user enters four integers and then displays the number of entries and the sum of the integers using a for loop. This is what I came up with.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   int sum = 0;
   int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i != 4 ; i++)
    {

      System.out.println(" Enter an integer: ");
      int num = in.nextInt();
      sum = sum + num;
      count = count + 1; 


  }  
  System.out.println("Number of entries: " + count);
  System.out.println("Total sum of entries: " + sum);   
 }   
}
```

I was wondering what a cleaner way was to ask the user for the four numbers using a for loop, and what other people might suggest be best for this situation. Thanks for any input, p.s. (I have just started learning!)

Comment: You could let the user enter all four numbers on a single line.  But what would your motivation be for changing what you already have?

Comment: Just curious to what other people would do in this situation and learn! Thanks for reply tho

Comment: I generally avoid using scanner class, I use bufferedreader along with String Tokenizer sometimes :)

Comment: Your `count` is already in `i`. No need to track it twice.

Comment: I would recommend you to start correctly intending your code for readability.    As someone else suggests you can allow user to enter all 4 numbers in a single line using hasNext() method from scanner and ask the user to type something like exit to finish input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int sum=0;
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
          System.out.println("ENter Number"+(i+1));
          sum += sc.nextInt();
      }
     System.out.println("the Sum is "+sum);
       sc.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with enter. If user presses enter, you can break.

```
enterkey = readinput.nextLine();
System.out.print(enterkey);

if(enterkey.equals("")){
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're a beginner it's the best way for getting input from the user in console. But you are for the condition should be like:
`for ( int i =0;i < 4 ; i ++){}`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this solution. I cleaned it up a bit. Maybe you will find some design decisions I made which will help you in the future:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int count = 1; count <= 4; count++) {
            System.out.print(String.format("Please enter %d. integer: ", count));
            sum = sum + readNumber(scanner);
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of numbers entered is: " + sum);
    }
}

private static int readNumber(Scanner scanner) {
    do {
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.print(String.format("Input %s is not a valid integer. Try again: ", input));
        }
    } while (true);
}
```